# Compile error in Android

Tags: java, android

Can anyone shed some light on this for me? I'm buiding this app for my final project that's due on Friday. Head. is. FRIED.

Getting this error on build

```
C:\Users\Gary\AndroidStudioProjects\NatureAll.v2\app\src\main\java\com\example\gary\natureallv2\SearchAnimalActivity.java:58: error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to String
                    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(POST,
                                                                                ^
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
1 error
```

It's telling me int can't be converted to string but I can't see where the int is. Here's my code:

```
package com.example.gary.natureallv2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

/**
 * Created by Gary on 12/09/2016.Go Me
 */
public class SearchAnimalActivity extends AppCompatActivity{



        EditText etSearchName;
        Button btnSearch;
        RequestQueue requestQueue;
        String showUrl = "http://192.168.1.10/myDocs/mainProject/search_animal_and.php";
       // String showUrl = "http://192.168.1.10/tutorial/showStudents.php";
        TextView tvName;
        TextView tvLatinName;
        TextView tvDescription;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.search_animal_activity);
            etSearchName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSearchName);
            tvName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvName);
            tvLatinName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLatinName);
            tvDescription = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDescription);
            btnSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);



            requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

            btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                   // System.out.println("ww");
                    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                            showUrl, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            System.out.println(response.toString());
                            try {
                                JSONArray animals = response.getJSONArray("animals");
                                for (int i = 0; i < animals.length(); i++) {
                                    JSONObject animal = animals.getJSONObject(i);
//Change here for different string names
                                    String name = animal.getString("name");
                                    String latinName = animal.getString("latinName");
                                    String description = animal.getString("description");

                                    tvName.append(name);
                                    tvLatinName.append(latinName);
                                    tvDescription.append(description);
                                }
                                //result.append("===\n");

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            System.out.append(error.getMessage());

                        }
                    });
                    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
                }
            });




        }

    }
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: `POST` is the `int`.

Comment: Do you use the newest version? Should work with it: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/master/src/main/java/com/android/volley/toolbox/JsonObjectRequest.java

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance, newest version of what? Android, volley, gradle?

Comment: Volley, and if it is included in Android, then Android. Or check which versions of the `JsonObjectRequest` constructor your current version provides.

Answer (score 0):

```
tvName.append(name);
tvLatinName.append(latinName);
tvDescription.append(description);
```

You are trying to append a string to a View which has a value of its id (int). This wont work. you should instead call a `.setText()` on your view and set the text to its current value plus what you want to append.